# node.js can't find module from relative path

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have two simple files in node.js and want to export two classes from one file and import them in the other. I'm using:

```
module.exports = {TrigInter, Hilbert};
```

Now, if I call require, it only works with the absolute file path:

```
const lib = require("/Users/username/documents/atom/project_folder/lib.js");
```

and not with the relative file path:

```
const lib = require("./lib.js");
```

eventhough the two files are both located in the "project_folder". I'm pretty sure, I tried the exact same thing before and it worked with the relative path. I don't see what I'm doing wrong. What am I missing?

Comment: May you update the question with a simplified file tree? Also, where are you running the node process from? where is the node entry file located?

Comment: Try `require( __dirname + "/lib.js")`

Comment: I'm working on a Mac. My files (index.js and lib.js) are in a project folder in my "Documents" folder (path in the example). I'm working on Atom with the Script package. I open Atom with my Terminal. Unfortunately `__dirname` doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

Absolute path is not best practice to use, instead you can use path join method like

```
const path = require('path');
let your_file_path = path.resolve(__dirname, '/lib.js');
```

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/nodejs-how-to-use__dirname

Comment: I know, that's why I'm asking, as I don't want to use the absolute path. Unfortunately your suggestion with `__dirname` doesn't work either, which is really strange, as it should be the same to what I was doing...